# IndexPath not showing correct number for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to grab the row clicked on value for the index.

I push it in with the next controller like so

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    nextView.count = [counts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

counts shows an array with 4 integer values correctly and row shows the correct position, but for some reason nextView.count becomes some weird 8 digit number, not sure why?

I call count in the nextViewController like so:

```
@interface nextViewController : UIViewController {

    int count;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int count;
```

So i.e. the count looks like this [3, 6, 2, 5], depending on the index the row can look like 0, 1, 2, or 3, but then the result for nextView.count = 3943493

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Objective-C collections such as `NSArray` can only store Objective-C *objects*.
So

```
 [counts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

returns an object, probably an `NSNumber`, but `nextView.count` is a (scalar) integer.
You have to use

```
 nextView.count = [[counts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue];
```

(What happens in your case is that the *address* of the object is assigned to the integer.)

Comment: thanks yeah I tried (int)[counts... but that didnt work but this did

Comment: @Lion789: `(int)[...]` only casts the pointer to an integer to make the compiler happy. You have to call a *method* to get the integer value of the number object.